# Pie chart as nodes in networkx

Tags: python, matplotlib, pie-chart, networkx

I want to know how I can plot a network (if I can), but instead of circles as nodes, I want a pie chart, because I have a graph with communities and I want to represent each one with the number of people who work in each department.

EDIT:
Ok, I've just tried this code and the result is Ok:

```
import community
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import random as rnd
import operator as op
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches
import math

Com = nx.Graph()

Com.add_nodes_from(['0','1','2','3','4'])
comlist=[('0','2',5.0),('3','0',3.0),('1','3',1.0),('2','3',7.3)]
Com.add_weighted_edges_from(comlist)
ListDeps = ['literature','maths','science','physical education']
HistCom = {'0':{'literature':20,
                'maths':24,
                'science':12},
           '1':{'literature':1,
                'physical education':14,
                'science':6},
           '2':{'science':15},
           '3':{'physical education':4,
                'maths':20},
           '4':{'literature':20,
                'maths':24,
                'science':12}}

pos=nx.spring_layout(Com)

fig=plt.figure(figsize=(5,5))
ax=plt.axes([0,0,1,1])
ax.set_aspect('equal')
nx.draw_networkx_edges(Com,pos,ax=ax)

plt.xlim(-0.5,1.5)
plt.ylim(-0.5,1.5)

trans=ax.transData.transform
trans2=fig.transFigure.inverted().transform

piesize=0.1 #Degree
p2=piesize/2.0

dep_color = dict()
for com in Com:
    xx,yy=trans(pos[com]) # figure coordinates
    xa,ya=trans2((xx,yy)) # axes coordinates
    a = plt.axes([xa-p2,ya-p2, piesize, piesize])
    a.set_aspect('equal')
    contats = len(HistCom[com].items())
    fracs = []
    ColorFrac = []
    for dep,n in sorted(HistCom[com].items(), key=op.itemgetter(1), reverse=True):
        fracs.append(n/sum(HistCom[com].values()))
        dep_color[dep] = dep_color.get(dep, (rnd.random(),rnd.random(),rnd.random()))
        ColorFrac.append(dep_color[dep])
    a.pie(fracs, colors = ColorFrac)


P = [mpatches.Patch(color=dep_color[dep], label=dep) for dep in dep_color]
plt.legend(handles=P,bbox_to_anchor=(0.,1.02,1.,.102), loc=3,ncol=3, mode="expand", borderaxespad=0.)
plt.show()
```

The problem that I have is when I try to plot the legend, I tried to put it above the plot but it appears in the middle.

Comment: See http://matplotlib.org/examples/api/scatter_piecharts.html which require some doing. The pie function also has a kwarg to set it's center (but I think only on master) so you can use networkx to get the centers / draw the edges then use one of the two techniques above to draw the markers.  I don't think there is a complete turn-key solution for what you want.

Comment: Also, yous question is being down voted because it is rather vauge/has no code.  I would suggest trying one of the two things I suggested and when you have _specific_ problems ask a new question about that problem and you will get a much better response. ('I tried code X, it should be doing Y, but it is doing Y-prime.  What is going on?')

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is something I posted to the networkx-discuss mailing list a while back.  The "transforms" part is not quite right (need matplotlib expert) so the scaling doesn't work right.  But it's a start,

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
G=nx.complete_graph(4)
pos=nx.spring_layout(G)

fig=plt.figure(figsize=(5,5))
ax=plt.axes([0,0,1,1])
ax.set_aspect('equal')
nx.draw_networkx_edges(G,pos,ax=ax)

plt.xlim(-0.5,1.5)
plt.ylim(-0.5,1.5)

trans=ax.transData.transform
trans2=fig.transFigure.inverted().transform

piesize=0.2
p2=piesize/2.0
for n in G:
    xx,yy=trans(pos[n]) # figure coordinates
    xa,ya=trans2((xx,yy)) # axes coordinates
    a = plt.axes([xa-p2,ya-p2, piesize, piesize])
    a.set_aspect('equal')
    fracs = [15,30,45, 10]
    a.pie(fracs)

plt.savefig('pc.png')
```

[image]